# How to use parameter from function to create an URL? Laravel Routing

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I'm sending an URL hashed and when i get it i have to show a view on Laravel, so i have those functions on the controller and also some routes:

This are my routes:

```
Route::post('/sendLink', 'Payment\PaymentController@getPaymentLink');
Route::get('/payment?hash={link}', 'Payment\PaymentController@show');
```

And this are the functions i have on my controller:

```
 public function getPaymentLink (Request $request){
    $budgetId = $request['url.com/payment/payment?hash'];
    $link = Crypt::decryptString($budgetId);
    Log::debug($link);
    //here to the show view i wanna send the link with the id hashed, thats why i dont call show($link)
    $view = $this->show($budgetId);
}

public function show($link) {
    $config = [
        'base_uri' => config('payment.base_uri'),        ];

    $client = new Client($config);

    $banking_entity = $client->get('url')->getBody()->getContents();
    $array =  json_decode($banking_entity, true);
    return view('payment.payment-data')->with('banking_entity', $array);
}
```

And this is getting a "Page not found" message error.
What i want to to is that when i the client clicks on the link i send him that has this format "url.com/payment/payment?hash=fjadshkfjahsdkfhasdkjha", trigger the getPaymentLink function so i can get de decrypt from that hash and also show him the view .

Comment: Make your route `Route::get('/payments', 'Payment\PaymentController@show');` and on GET request it will automatically converts as `/payments?hash=hahshgs` from controller you can catch it as `$hash = request('hash');`

Comment: Are you saying that i should put the $hash = request('hash') on my show function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define route like this:

```
Route::get('/payment/{hash}', 'Payment\PaymentController@show');
```

You can now simply use it in your Controller method like below:

```
<?php 

 public function getPaymentLink (Request $request,$hash){
    $budgetId = $hash;
    // further code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

there is no need to `?hash={link}` in get route

it's query params and it will received with `$request`

like:

```php
   $request->hash 

   // or

   $request->get('hash')
```

Comment: yes, but don't forget to inject Request ```public function show(Request $request)```